# How to completely remove Ubuntu 12.04 after restoring computer to factory settings?

Tags: 12.04, windows, wubi, uninstall

I have reset my computer to factory settings (without knowing that Ubuntu will not be uninstalled). After setting up, Ubuntu was still listed at the start up boot manager, when I selected it, it gave me errors. Ubuntu 12.04 also stole my 18GB hard drive. Now, I can’t find Ubuntu uninstaller in my programs nor I can’t find Ubuntu files in my C drive. By the way, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with WUBI installer. How do I completely remove Ubuntu from my computer? Please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How to completely remove Ubuntu installed with Wubi...

**Normal uninstall**

Uninstall it by going to the control panel, Add/Remove programs and find the `Ubuntu` entry and double click to automatically uninstall.

**Manual Uninstall**

If the normal uninstall didn't work for some reason e.g. you already manually deleted the `\ubuntu` directory manually or did a factory restore) you should follow the instructions in the [Wubi guide to manually uninstall](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F).

If you think that there's still some space 'stolen' from your drive, then you should run `chkdsk /f` (note that this requires a reboot if you're running it on the `C:` drive). After that, look in the hidden, protected folder `\found.000` (or `.001` etc.) and look within that for any file that is Gigabytes in size and remove it. (If you had important data you lost, don't remove it, you can probably recover the data... but that's another topic).

One area that is fiddly is the BCD store for Windows Vista/7. If you've tried to manually remove Ubuntu or done that factory restore, but the `Ubuntu` entry remains, then it's simple to remove it using `bcdedit`:

To use `bcdedit`, run `cmd.exe` (**Run as administrator**), then enter `bcdedit` to show all boot entries, note the `{GUID}` specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it: `bcdedit /delete {GUID}`

Here's an example:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {6529eb15-62be-11e0-b237-a8486d1f5063}
displayorder            {current}
                        {c001df0c-5ec0-11e1-a466-005056c00008}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {6529eb17-62be-11e0-b237-a8486d1f5063}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {6529eb15-62be-11e0-b237-a8486d1f5063}
nx                      OptIn

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {c001df0c-5ec0-11e1-a466-005056c00008}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu

C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /delete {c001df0c-5ec0-11e1-a466-005056c00008}
```

Make sure you run `cmd.exe` as an administrator (not logged in an administrator account... there is a difference).

Comment: Well informed tutorials, this was what I was looking for. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can go online to [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on a different computer and download the Ubuntu Live CD software. Install it to a USB drive or burn it to a disk following the instructions. Boot up your computer using that. If you need to copy your files to save them (if you don't have a backup) then get an external hard disk (I'm not sure if a flash drive can handle the size of your files) and copy all your files to it. Then, after that is done, on the Live CD (you should have been doing all these steps on the Ubuntu Live CD by the way) start a clean install of Ubuntu. If you DON'T want Ubuntu anymore, use the Live CD to reformat your disk. You should be fine, after that.

Comment: Thank for your comment but my computer is a netbook and doesn't have a external cd drive :'(

Comment: Not a problem. Just create a bootable USB drive instead:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: I get errors after ubuntu logo...